# An expression for $E(r) - E(\sqrt{r^2 - 1})$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $r$ be a real in $(1 , \infty)$ and let $E$ be the integer part function. Do you know any easier expression for $E(r) - E(\sqrt{r^2 - 1})$ depending of $r$? If $x \in \mathbb{R}$, the Fourier series for $E(x)$ is
$$
E(x) = x - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{\pi} \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(2 \pi k x)}{k}\mbox{.}
$$
Thus, we can state that
$$
E(r) - E(\sqrt{r^2 - 1}) = r - \sqrt{r^2 - 1} + \frac{1}{\pi} \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(2 \pi k r) - \sin(2 \pi k \sqrt{r^2 - 1})}{k}\mbox{,}
$$
but it looks a difficult expression, unless it can be simplified.